# enable counsel-projectile by default

Tags: init-file, projectile, ivy, counsel, multiple-modes

I want to enable `counsel-projectile-mode` by default.

I have added `(counsel-projectile-mode)` to `.emacs` file as per project's usage guide but it doesn't work; meaning `projectile` still uses `ido` for finding files and such) ...

But after the Emacs is open if i `M-x counsel-projectile-mode` twice to disable and re-enable it, from within emacs, it will start working. (meaning `projectile` will use `counsel` for finding files, instead of using `ido`)

Any idea what's wrong?

[This](https://paste.centos.org/view/ebee3397) is my `.emacs` file.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you have both `(counsel-projectile-mode)` and `(counsel-projectile-mode nil)` in your .emacs file. Have you tried simply adding a [hook](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Hooks.html) to start `(counsel-projectile-mode)` when loading projectile? Delete (or comment out) the lines you currently have for counsel-projectile-mode and try this:

```lisp
(add-hook 'projectile-mode-hook 'counsel-projectile-mode)
```

Comment: I added the one with nil for testing, after the first one wouldn't work ... (it didn't work with nil either)
  
tried the hook but apparently it gets into some sort of loop ... and doesn't work either ...

Comment: I solved the problem, but not sure what's the deal, gonna make a bug report

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to the `.emacs` file, solves the problem:

```
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook 'counsel-projectile-mode)
```